# How to create yaml egg file?

Tags: python, pyyaml

I want to create egg file from python yaml
http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML

I modified the setup.py to import setup from setuptools (the last line)

```
from distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext as _build_ext                                                                                                                                                    
from distutils.command.bdist_rpm import bdist_rpm as _bdist_rpm                                                                                                                                                    
from distutils.errors import DistutilsError, CompileError, LinkError, DistutilsPlatformError  

from setuptools import setup
```

When I invoke the build command

```
python setup.py bdist_egg
```

It gave me this error:

```
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: invalid command 'bdist_egg'
```

Do you know how to make it work?

Comment: Unfortunately egg is the only file support by pyspark if you want to load external python lib

Answer (score 0):

I know this is ancient, but I just had to do this

1. Download from the github repo
2. From the clone directory, run: python setup.py install
3. Retrieve pyyaml.egg from the "dist" directory